Migrated site redirects pages to front page on localhost
I migrated a Drupal 10 website that was created with my online server hosting applications, to a localhost (WAMP). The migrated site only shows homepage and redirects all other pages to the localhost front page (on WAMP).  localhost/drupal/pages will be redirected to localhost/pages.
Where can I edit my base URL settings?

Did you migrate the hidden files like .htaccess as well? Is your Wamp environment fully compatible with Drupal? Check the requirements. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/system-requirements/web-server-requirements

WAMP is yesteryear tech. Switch to DDEV now.
